# Dual space of Bessel potential space

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

We define the Bessel potential space on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as
$$H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{u\in \mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)| (I-\Delta )^{\frac s2}u\in L^p \} $$
where $(I-\Delta)^{\frac s2}u= \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left((1+|\xi|^2 )^\frac s2\hat u \right)$. It is known that $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ when $s\in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, we define $W^{-s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=(W^{s,p’}(\mathbb{R}^n ) )’$. So does this definition correspond to Bessel’s case? that is, does $H^{-s,p}=(H^{s,p’})’$?

Comment: How do you define $p'$?

Comment: $p’$ is the adjoins of $p$, i.e. $\frac 1p’+\frac 1p=1$. @pax

Comment: what does it mean by $(I-\Delta)^{\frac s2}u= \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left((1+|\xi|^2 )^\frac s2\hat u \right) \in L^p$ since $(I-\Delta)^{\frac s2}u$ is also a tempered distribution? how can we define a $L^p$ norm to a distribution?